# Couchbase lite - user access control

Tags: authentication, couchdb, access-control, couchbase-lite

I want to share data between multiple devices and users running a couchdb server on iriscouch.com and using couchbase-lite on ios and android. Users should be able to login with facebook and email. How do I handle user access to specific documents? I dont dont want anyone to be able to access the documents and databases. I thought about using HTTP basic auth ([replication security](http://developer.couchbase.com/mobile/develop/guides/couchbase-lite/native-api/replication/index.html)), hard coding username and password into the app code. Unfortunately it is sent as plain text and seems totally insecure. Can you help me out with some ideas about this scenario?

Comment: I'm developing a similar APP (CouchDB + Couchbase Lite for Android) and I wonder how you managed to login with Facebook and/email. Does this also mean _register_ a new user? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use SSL ecncryption for security. Please refer the link for enabling SSL
https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/How_to_enable_SSL.

I had similar problem while using Basic Auth, hence we had to use SSL to make it more secure.

If can follow this method If you want to use Basic AUth. 
1. Encode the username and Password
    ex: username@password which after encoding becomes dXNlcm5hbWVAcGFzc3dvcmQ=
(use https://www.base64encode.org/ to encode).

2. Using curl try to authenticate

   > curl -v -H "Authorization: Basic dXNlcm5hbWVAcGFzc3dvcmQ=" -H "Content-  type:application/json" -X GET IP_Address_and_DatabaseName

In this way you can hide the Username and Password but still anyone can have the encoded string. Hence If possible, try to implement SSL.

Comment: that sounds great! thank you so much. the only thing im not sure is if couchbase lite for ios and android support this type of authentification. i will try this and leave a comment!

Comment: I honestly don't know how to do it in couchdb, but with Couchbase Mobile lite it is possible. See this link: http://ti.eng.br/couchbase-mobile-with-jwt-tokens/